# PHP Converting A Date to Unix Timestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to convert a date of the format `25/July/2015` obtained from jQuery UI datepicker widget to UNIX timestamp using `strtotime()` function, but it's not working, nothing(blank) is returned, how do I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', ' ','25/July/2015'));
```